# Python Modify OS Path Variable

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, xgboost

I am going to try and say this right but it's a bit outside my area of expertise.

I am using the xgboost library in a windows environment with Python 2.7 which requires all kinds of nasty compiling and installation.

That done, the instructions I'm following tell me I need to modify the OS Path Variable in an iPython notebook before I actually import the library for use.

The instructions tell me to run the following:

```
import os

mingw_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\\mingw64\\bin'

os.environ['PATH'] = mingw_path + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
```

then I can import

```
import xgboost as xgb
import numpy as np
....
```

This works.  My question.  Does the OS path modification make a **permanent** change in the path variable or do I need to modify the os path variable each time I want to use it as above?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Here is a link to the [instructions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en) I'm following.  The part I'm referencing is toward the end.

Comment: Please cite the instructions you're following so we get a context and also the process from start to beginning.

Comment: AJK - added as requested under EDIT above

Comment: Windows persists environment variables in the registry. There's an app to modify this in the control panel in System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables. This app allows modifying the value of `Path` either for the current user or the system. When a user logs on, the per-user `Path` value gets appended to the system value. The control panel app also sends a window message to tell Explorer to reload its environment variables from the registry. But existing cmd shells and most other processes will have to be restarted to see the new `Path` value.

Comment: Side-note: If you want portable code (obviously not the case here given the fully hard coded Windows path), use `os.pathsep`, not a hardcoded `;`. On *NIX systems, the `PATH` separator is `:`, and `os.pathsep` will switch to match the OS.

Comment: @eryksun I actually was instructed to modify the windows (computer) PATH variable as you describe earlier in the instructions (link provided above under EDIT).  I'm not sure of the reason - this is outside my scope of knowledge.  If I have the computer PATH variable modified would I then need to add this path modification for Python?  The instructions suggest I do but maybe not?

Comment: You need to start a new command prompt to see the updated value. Then you won't need to modify `os.environ['Path']` in Python. I'd add it to the per-user `Path` (create the value if it doesn't exist). The per-user value usually has just a few entries that are simple to maintain for your own needs. But note that the per-user value gets appended instead of prepended to the system value, so system directories are searched first.

Answer (score 2):

The `os.environ` function is only inside the scope of the python/jupyter console:

Here's evidence of this in my bash shell:

```
$ export A=1
$ echo $A
1
$ python -c "import os; print(os.environ['A']); os.environ['A'] = '2'; print(os.environ['A'])"
1
2
$ echo $A
1
```

The python line above, prints the environ variable `A` and then changes it's value and prints it again.

So, as you see, any `os.environ` variable is changed within the python script, but when it gets out, the environment of the bash shell does not change.

Another way of doing this is to modify your User or System `PATH` variable. But this may break other things because what you're doing may replace the default compiler with mingw and complications may arise. I'm not a windows expert, so not sure about that part.

In a nutshell:

- The os.environ manipulations are local only to the python process
- It won't affect any other program
- It has to be done every time you want to import xgboost

Comment: That's a bummer.  Annoying to have to remember to throw that code in each time I plan to use the library if that is the case