# Point Python to 64-bit Java saved locally by changing PATH within session?

Tags: java, python

Python currently defaults to `32-bit` Java as its installed on my enterprise computer and its causing compatibility issues with some packages. I do not have rights to install `64-bit` within Windows itself.

So as an alternative, I'm trying to point Python towards a `64-bit` version of Java saved locally so it would use it for the session, while not modifying overall functionality in Windows.

Is there a way to achieve this? I seemed to be able to do so in Rstudio with the following lines of code:

```
old_JAVA_HOME <- Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "N:/Computer/Java/JDK")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Modify OS Path Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540728/python-modify-os-path-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "N:/Computer/Java/JDK"
```

This will be limited to the current session only.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I had to put quotes around "JAVA_HOME"